# How to pass a Drawable_icon to backend code?

Tags: android, kotlin, xml-drawable

- I want to access a default icon (cross) in Android Studio itself, called ic_delete, in the definition section of deleteButton in the code below. But I don't know how to pass it to my backend code.
  When I use the following code to call it, I get an error and the code does not recognize it.
  `deleteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete)`
- The second problem is, how should I set textParams.gravity so that the entered text is placed exactly in the centre of the TextView (both horizontally and vertically)?
  [[part1 of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv80t.png)]

[part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EOD7.png)

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
deleteButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_delete))
```